# How to store Vue.js components as objects in a database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I want to store a vuejs component (say, the HelloWorld component you usually have in a brand new installation of vue) in a database. Is there some sort of serialization procedure/package that I can use to serialize vuejs components? Thanks :)

Comment: Just curious - why? What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to build an app that lets people build components without coding (through wizards and stuff) and I want them to share those components with other people.

Comment: If all you need is the component then you don't even need the database @Morpheus.47. Just save it to a file and save it's location along with other meta data you may need to your database table

Comment: @klanmiko But how to deal with versions and forward support? I think it would be good to manage with a database.

Comment: @Luciens you could have versioning info as file metadata, or you could have an index. The application as a whole may use a database but this part of such an application will not be improved by dumping text or binary data into a database

Answer (score 1):

Use the Vue `<component/>` tag to create a placeholder. It will allow a `null` `:is` property whilst we fetch a module from the server (think database).

```html
<component id="app" :is="componentName"></component> <!-- null for now -->
```

Now let's go fetch a module from the database on the server. In my case, I use a Spring controller mapped to `.mjs`fetches the Javascript from the database and returns it with a text/javascript mime type.

```js
export default {
    data: {
        componentName: null
    },
    async beforeMount() {
        const module = await import('/components/random-component.mjs')
        const rawComponent = module.default;
        const componentName = rawComponent.name;
        Vue.component(componentName, rawComponent);
        this.componentName = componentName;
    },
}
```

The code above fetches an ES6 module with a dynamic import and then registers it using a Vue.component() call.

And the content of the module:

```js
export default {
    name: "page",
    data() {
        return {
            message: "Hello World",
        }
    },
    template: "<h1>{{message}}</h1>"
}
```

More in the official Vue.ks documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html